# Label a matrix by characters

Tags: matrix, label, latex

How to add labels as in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Please add [**your code**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can edit it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below I use an updated version of [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox` (defined as `\eqmathbox[<tag>]`) to capture/measure the width of boxes with a specific `<tag>` in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox,xparse,bm,amsmath}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \eqmathbox[y-mat]{
    \begin{bmatrix}
      y(\bm{x}_1) \\
        \vdots    \\
      y(\bm{x}_n)
    \end{bmatrix}
  }
  &\sim
  \mathcal{N}
  \eqmathbox[brackets]{\left(
    \eqmathbox[0-mat]{
      \begin{bmatrix}
          0    \\
        \vdots \\
          0
      \end{bmatrix}
    },
    \eqmathbox[K-mat]{
      \begin{bmatrix}
        k(\bm{x}_1, \bm{x}_1) & \dots  & k(\bm{x}_1, \bm{x}_N) \\
               \vdots         & \ddots &       \vdots          \\
        k(\bm{x}_N, \bm{x}_1) & \dots  & k(\bm{x}_N, \bm{x}_N)
      \end{bmatrix}
    }
    +
    \sigma^2
    \eqmathbox[I-mat]{
      \begin{bmatrix}
          1    & \dots  &   0    \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
          0    & \dots  &   1
      \end{bmatrix}
    }
  \right)} \\
  \eqmathbox[y-mat]{
    \bm{y}
  }
  &\phantom{{}\sim{}}
  \phantom{\mathcal{N}}
  \eqmathbox[brackets]{
    \eqmathbox[0-mat]{
      \bm{0}
    }
    \phantom{{},{}}
    \eqmathbox[K-mat]{
      \bm{K}
    }
    \phantom{{}+{}}
    \sigma^2
    \eqmathbox[I-mat]{
      \bm{I}
    }
  }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```